# signatures in oulook 2010 Windows

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

In earlier versions of Outlook, adding a signature to an email made that signature the default (a hihgly useful feature!) until it was changed by selecting a different signature.  For example, on new emails I use a complete signature with name, phone, email, company, etc; on replies, only a three line, name, company and phone.  Now I have to scroll through the list if I am adding a signature.  Microsoft, why don't you ask people about such features before discarding them?

Anyone know how to implement this feature on outlook 2010 or to set one signature as the default?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they've just moved it to be an account setting instead of a signature setting.

1. In Outlook, click on the File tab
2. Select Options from left hand side
3. Click on Mail
4. Click the Signatures button
5. On the Email Signature tab in the Signature and Stationary dialog box choose your email account that you wish to set the signature for, from the E-mail account drop down box
6. Choose the signature you wish to use on new messages from the New messages drop down box
7. If you want to specify a different signature for replies and forwarded messages, choose that one in the replies/forwards drop down box, otherwise choose the same signature there. If you leave it blank   then no signature will be added to replies or forwarded emails automatically.
8. When you’ve finished modifying your signature settings click OK on the Signatures and Stationary box

From [here](http://www.microsofttraining.net/tip-683-default-email-signature.html).

Comment: Not what I was looking for.  I've already set the default in this fashion, but in the earlier versions, the signature selected in the drop down list was the last one used, so that alt-i-s inserted the same signature as the last one.  With the current version, you can add signatures to the quick key list, but it doesn't then list the signatures as described above.

Comment: Does the old solution work when you set winword.exe as the default editor? (In Outlook 2003 signature changing broke if you did not set that. Not idea how OL2010 handles that).

Comment: I do not believe I was using word in Outlook 2003 as the editor.

Comment: Ah I see. You want to have selecting one change the default instead of having a single default for new vs reply?